# dr racket accumulator help understanding

Tags: racket

Problem: 
  Design a function that consumes a list of numbers and produces
  a list of every other number in the list. So

```
 (skip1 (list 1 4 2 6 9 5)) produces (list 1 2 9)

 (define (skip1 lon0)

 (local [(define (skip1 lon i)
        (cond [(empty? lon) empty]
              [else
               (if (odd? i)  
                   (cons (first lon) 
                         (skip1 (rest lon) (add1 i)))
                   (skip1 (rest lon) (add1 i)))]))]
(skip1 lon0 1)))
```

Can anyone explain how it works after the function if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, I know the course this comes from. You go to UBC right? Anyways...

The `i` is an accumulator that keeps track of the position in the list you are at. The trampoline call starts with the whole list, so the initial position is just `1`. After you make the first recursive call, the first element is stripped off, so the new starting position is `2`. This proceeds until you get to the end of the list (of say `n` elements) at which point `i` is `n`.

So, you want a function that keeps only the numbers in odd position, so you want to discard those not in an odd position. `(odd? i)` then tells you if the first element of `lon` is in an odd position in the initial list. If this element is in an odd position, we keep the element, and cons it onto a recursive call for the rest of the list, otherwise we discard the item and just move onto the recursive call.

Try stepping through an example. The `if` part is just about the choice of keeping or not keeping the first element of `lon` in the final result.

Comment: so for these accumulators everytime a recursive call is done, that first element is off until all of them are gone? like applies to everything

Comment: I'd be careful before saying that that is always the case, but it is often so. I think your question is more about recursion here: all recursive functions on lists will operate on the first element (recursively) until the list is empty.